# R - Loop through df of IDs and Zipcodes to find next closest store (lat/longitude), return list of Store ID, and next closest Store

Tags: r, loops, zipcode

I've used the zipcode package to get the latitude and longitude of zipcodes of a bunch of stores based on zipcode.

I'm hoping to figure out a way to loop through the list, and for each of the 5000 stores, find the next closest store based on Long/Lat.

I've currently got this data frame (with values removed for this post):

```
'data.frame':   1206 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ zip      : Factor w/ 1182 levels "86645","43225",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ ID       : int  
 $ city     : chr  
 $ state    : chr  
 $ latitude : num  
 $ longitude: num
```

Comment: Can you share part of your data so that we can present a solution? You can use `dput(head(mydataframe,10))`.

Comment: I have some sample data above - thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution that I could think of:

```
library(data.table)
library(zipcode)
library(geosphere)
data(zipcode)
set.seed(151)
n <- 100
storeData <- data.table(storeID=sample(1:100000,n,replace = FALSE),zip=sample(zipcode$zip,n,replace = TRUE))
zipcode <- data.table(zipcode,key = "zip")
storeData <- zipcode[storeData,on="zip"][!is.na(latitude)|!is.na(longitude)]
storeData
storeData
# zip             city state latitude  longitude storeID
# 1: 22408   Fredericksburg    VA 38.23602  -77.46111   47945
# 2: 44515       Youngstown    OH 41.09901  -80.74545   86541
# 3: 48112       Belleville    MI 42.23993  -83.15082   77807
# 4: 80154        Englewood    CO 39.73875 -104.40835   53862
# 5: 73766       Pond Creek    OK 36.66271  -97.83063   44166
# 6: 32321          Bristol    FL 30.36007  -84.97668   61377
# 7: 49442         Muskegon    MI 43.23262  -86.19550   45492
# 8: 04537         Boothbay    ME 43.90781  -69.64608   82087
storeDistances <- distm(storeData[,.(longitude,latitude)],storeData[,.(longitude,latitude)])
colnames(storeDistances) <- rownames(storeDistances) <- storeData[,storeID]
getClosest <- function(number=1){
  apply(storeDistances,1,function(x) (colnames(storeDistances)[which(x==sort(x)[number+1])]))
}
storeData[,firstClosest:=getClosest(1)]
storeData[,secondClosest:=getClosest(2)]
storeData[,thirdClosest:=getClosest(3)]
storeData
# zip             city state latitude  longitude storeID firstClosest secondClosest
# 1: 22408   Fredericksburg    VA 38.23602  -77.46111   47945        70091         41024
# 2: 44515       Youngstown    OH 41.09901  -80.74545   86541        10806         78898
# 3: 48112       Belleville    MI 42.23993  -83.15082   77807        25906         94780
# 4: 80154        Englewood    CO 39.73875 -104.40835   53862        22347         91392
# 5: 73766       Pond Creek    OK 36.66271  -97.83063   44166         4816         90090
# 6: 32321          Bristol    FL 30.36007  -84.97668   61377         8187          1937
# 7: 49442         Muskegon    MI 43.23262  -86.19550   45492        95486         97241
# 8: 04537         Boothbay    ME 43.90781  -69.64608   82087        46720          7013
# 
# thirdClosest
# 1:        57562
# 2:        71232
# 3:        86541
# 4:        97986
# 5:          146
# 6:         8113
# 7:         6400
# 8:        10872
```

`storeDistances` is a matrix of distances between each store. The `getClosest` function gets the closest store.

Comment: @MegCantwell I have created a sample data and this is just a reference and might not work exactly with your data. You might need to modify it a little bit to make it work with your data, like changing names, data types, etc..

Comment: @MegCantwell `for` loops are usually inefficient so I try to avoid them. Is there any particular function that you need the explanation for? I have written some explanation in my answer but I don't know if that's enough.

Comment: @A Gore - looks like the code is a little buggy for some of the zip codes... in the csv output, there's a bunch of c("store ID", "Store ID", "store ID") - with the storeID being other store IDS - interesting that it happens to only some of the stores... any thoughts/ I'm trying to QC

Comment: @mcando That might happen because if two stores are equidistant from a specific store then they both will be chosen.